# Why UPDATE does not see result of subquery? [Oracle]

Tags: database, oracle

After this query updated 0 rows:

```
UPDATE F_ANSWER fa 
SET fa.STATUS_ID = 5 
WHERE fa.ANSWER_ID IN (SELECT FA1.ANSWER_ID 
                       FROM F_ANSWER FA1 
                       WHERE FA1.ANSWER_ID = (SELECT ANSWER_ID 
                                              FROM F_ANSWER FA2 
                                              WHERE FA2.QUERY_ID = FA1.QUERY_ID 
                                              ORDER BY ANSWER_ID DESC 
                                              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) 
);
```

but separately SELECT returned 2 rows with ID:

```
SELECT FA1.ANSWER_ID 
FROM F_ANSWER FA1 
WHERE FA1.ANSWER_ID = (SELECT ANSWER_ID FROM F_ANSWER FA2
```

Why is that?

Simplified subquery without link from subquery to query works fine:

```
UPDATE F_ANSWER fa 
SET fa.STATUS_ID = 5 
WHERE fa.ANSWER_ID IN (SELECT FA1.ANSWER_ID 
                       FROM F_ANSWER FA1 
                       WHERE FA1.ANSWER_ID = (SELECT ANSWER_ID 
                                              FROM F_ANSWER FA2 
                                              ORDER BY ANSWER_ID DESC 
                                              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) 
);
```

I can resolve my problem with 2 queries - 1 for selecting necessary IDS and 2 for updating.

But it's interesting why update cannot see result of subquery with this structure.

Answer (score 0):

You written two different update-query options: (1) one is written with a correlated subquery, and the other(2) just with a subquery.

I believe, that your data is such that the predicate in upd-query (1)

```
         WHERE FA1.ANSWER_ID = (SELECT ANSWER_ID 
                          FROM F_ANSWER FA2 
                          WHERE FA2.QUERY_ID = 
                          FA1.QUERY_ID
                          ORDER BY ANSWER_ID DESC 
                          FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
```

cuts off the data.

1. in your main update query  this block is a correlated subquery

```
    UPDATE F_ANSWER fa 
    SET fa.STATUS_ID = 5 
    WHERE fa.ANSWER_ID IN (SELECT FA1.ANSWER_ID 
                           FROM F_ANSWER FA1 
                           WHERE FA1.ANSWER_ID = (SELECT ANSWER_ID 
                                                  FROM F_ANSWER FA2 
                                                  WHERE FA2.QUERY_ID = 
                                                        FA1.QUERY_ID
                                                  ORDER BY ANSWER_ID DESC 
                                                  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
    );
```

2. in this query, you are using a subquery without correlating by QUERY_ID(
   ....
   WHERE FA2.QUERY_ID = FA1.QUERY_ID
   ....
   ):

```
    UPDATE F_ANSWER fa 
    SET fa.STATUS_ID = 5 
    WHERE fa.ANSWER_ID IN (SELECT FA1.ANSWER_ID 
                           FROM F_ANSWER FA1 
                           WHERE FA1.ANSWER_ID = (SELECT ANSWER_ID 
                                              FROM F_ANSWER FA2 
                                              ORDER BY ANSWER_ID DESC 
                                              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
    );
```

You can provide an example of your data and formulate your task.
Your UPD-query  can be rewritten an easier.

Comment: Please explain!